# What is the effect of "${(@f)…}" in Zsh?

Tags: zsh, variable-substitution

I ran into a Zsh script and wanted to know its meaning. In the scripts below there is `${$(@f)$(egrep "$2","$file")}` expression. From what I searched, `@` is to use represent all positional parameters, but then the postfix letter `f` is not mentioned anywhere in above script and I couldn't find any online material saying its special meaning.

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

tmp_file="/tmp/_unsorted_find_n_grep"
echo "--- find <$2> in <$1>" > $tmp_file

find . -follow -iname "$1" | while read file
do
    timestamp=$(ls -l --time-style=+"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" "$file" | gawk '{print $6, $7}')
    linestack=${(@f)$(egrep "$2" "$file")}
    for line in $linestack 
do
    echo "$timestamp $file: $line" >> $tmp_file
done
done

cat $tmp_file | sort
rm $tmp_file
```

Answer (score 7):

The character inside the parentheses are [parameter expansion flags](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags). They can be used around a variable substitution or a command substitution, e.g.

```
${(@f)SOME_VARIABLE}
${(@f)${(xyz)SOME_VARIABLE}}
${(@f)$(some-command)}
```

The flag `f` splits the result of the expansion at newlines. The flag `@` ensures that the resulting array is expanded as multiple words; oddly, it only has effect inside double quotes, where it acts as a generalization of `"$@"`.

Usually, these flags are used like this:

```
lines=("${(@f)$(egrep "$2" "$file")}")
```

This way `lines` becomes an array where each element is one line of output from `egrep`.

Here, the expansion is not in a context that allows multiple words, so the `@` flag has no effect. The effect of the `f` flag is somewhat unintuitive: it forces an array context, so the IFS-separated words in the `egrep` output are stored in a temporary array which is then joined with the first character of `IFS`.

> ```
> linestack=${(@f)$(egrep "$2" "$file")}
> ```

Contrast:

```
$ zsh -c 'a=${(f)$(echo hello world; echo wibble)}; print -lr $#a $a'
18
hello world wibble
$ zsh -c 'IFS=:$IFS; a=${(f)$(echo hello world; echo wibble)}; print -lr $#a $a'
18
hello:world:wibble
$ zsh -c 'IFS=:; a=${(f)$(echo hello world; echo wibble)}; print -lr $#a $a'
18
hello world
wibble

$ zsh -c 'a=(${(f)$(echo hello world; echo wibble)}); print -lr $#a $a' 
1
hello world wibble
$ zsh -c 'a=("${(@f)$(echo hello world; echo wibble)}"); print -lr $#a $a'
2
hello world
wibble
```

Comment: Quite neat... Does `bash` have a built-in feature like this?

Comment: @GenePavlovsky Bash has [much more limited parameter expansion features](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html). A few of zsh's parameter expansion flags have a bash equivalent with a different syntax, but most have no convenient equivalent.

Comment: Thanks, I also looked in the manual but didn't find an equivalent to this. Never looked into learning zsh, but this feature in particular seems very convenient to have. In bash scripting, I normally use arrays to achieve this result, which is definitely less neat.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this zsh documentation](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/zsh_a4.pdf)

```
@    In double quotes, array elements are put into separate words. E.g., ‘"${(@)foo}"’
     is equivalent to ‘"${foo[@]}"’ and ‘"${(@)foo[1,2]}"’ is the same as ‘"$foo[1]"
     "$foo[2]"’. This is distinct from field splitting by the f, s or z flags, which still
     applies within each array element.
```